# Saving a model's relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3.

If I do something like this:

```
$posts = Post::where('id', 1)
    ->with('stats')
    ->first();
```

Is it possible to save the `stats` relationship, like:

```
$posts->stats->num_users = 5;
$posts->stats->save();
```

Is this the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does your code work? Because if it is, then why it should not be a correct way? Eager loading is nothing more than just joining model instances so it works in the same was as long as `$posts->stats` returns an instance of the model you want to update

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
$posts = Post::where('id', 1)
        ->with('stats')
        ->first();

$stats = $post->stats;
```

if you want to update the value then

```
$stats->update(['num_users'=> 5]);
```

that should do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

However, it could just be the 'stats' relation is not yet created on your post object.

If that's the case, you could do something like this:

```
//retrieve the post
$post = Post::with('stats')->find(1);

//use existing stats object or new up one
$stats = $post->stats ?: new PostStats(['post_id' => $post->id]);
$stats->num_users = 5;

//persist
$stats->save();
```